# N-step DQN question, confused by the termination states

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The one-step DQN is easy to understand, however, for N-step DQN, I am confused by the termination states. Here is my example trajectory:

$(s_0, a_0, s_1, r_0), (s_1, a_1, s_2, r_1), (s_2, a_2, s_3, r_2), (s_3, a_3, s_4, r_3), (s_4, a_4, s_5, r_4), (s_5, a_5, s_6, r_5), (s_6, a_6, s_7, r_6)$.

Items in the tuple are current state, current action, next state, current reward, respectively. The first item $s_6$ in the last tuple is the termination state.

My idea to calculate the N-step DQN (when $n=2$ and $\gamma=1$) is

$$
(r_0+\gamma * r_1+\gamma^2\max_a Q(s_2, a)-Q(s_0, a_0))^2 \\
(r_1+\gamma * r_2+\gamma^2\max_a Q(s_3, a)-Q(s_1, a_1))^2 \\
(r_2+\gamma *r_3+\gamma^2\max_a Q(s_4, a)-Q(s_2, a_2))^2 \\
(r_3+\gamma *r_4+\gamma^2\max_a Q(s_5, a)-Q(s_3, a_3))^2 \\
(r_4+\gamma *r_5+\gamma^2\max_a Q(s_6, a)-Q(s_4, a_4))^2 \\
(r_5+\gamma *r_6-Q(s_5, a_5))^2 \\
(r_6    -Q(s_6, a_6))^2 \\
$$

Is the squared TD loss correct?  Is for the last 2 rows correct? I think there are two termination states for the last 2 rows respectively.

Because in Sutton's book, I found it is the way to calculate the TD error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is the squared TD loss correct?

Yes

> Is for the last 2 rows correct?

Yes